# Text inside TextView of 2nd activity goes beyond the sceen but works for lager display phones

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-resources

I have two activities and I passed some data i.e username and password on click button to the `textviews` respectively of 2nd activity , the problem is that when I enter 12 characters in username `edittext` field it is passed and showed on 2nd activity but when try to enter more than 12 characters it is not showing the last characters other than the first 12 characters.

so how to display full text passed from 1st activity.

> note : i have set textview max lines to "1". (this my requirement)

```html
  first activity editText.xml
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
2nd activity textView.xml
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide padding to your view like below,

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_padding="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: build failed after i added android:layout_padding ="16dp" , showed an error of unknown attribute of padding

Comment: you can provide padding to it's parent view

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it worked..

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytextvieww"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```